# Standard Marker in Google Maps too small

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, zurb-foundation

i am implementing a Location Picker like this one:
http://m.rhinvivant-lebendigerrhein.eu/geopick.php?raz=1

But when I load the code in my environment the Location Marker is suddenly small and squashed after loading the page (see image1). Then after i dragged the Marker around, it gets even smaller (see image2).

[image: google maps marker too small]

Has anyone seen something like this? It would help to get a hint how i can work around this, or what mistake i made.

i.e. How can i fix the size of my markers?

My code looks like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: settings.gMapMarkerTitle,
    map: map,
    position: defaultLocationLatLng,
    draggable: true
});
```

Comment: I have no issues with the linked page.

Comment: Tried linked page in 3 browsers - no issues. Do you have browser extension installed that could be interfering?

Comment: to clarify, the linked page works also fine for me. i suppose the bug hatches when i include the example code into my project

Comment: It's hard to answer without any details about your project, but it looks like a CSS-issue. Are there any global formats for e.g. img-elements?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Problem was indeed a CSS setting. I am using the zurb foundation framework, which defines max-width for all images.

```
max-width: 100%;
```

Fixed it, by adding my own css class to the map div. It overrides the max-width setting and the Markers are back to normal.

```
<div id="gmap" class="map_canvas" />

.map_canvas img {
    max-width: none; // just in case it does not work... add !important;
}
```

Thanks Dr. Molle for the Hint...

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I got stuck on this issue as well while using the foundation framework - thanks for saving me the time! haha!

Comment: Bootstrap had a similar effect, though oddly only on Android vs. iOS & desktop which were fine

Answer (score 2):

Works without !important, and !important should not be used if it doesn't need to be.

```
.map_canvas img {
    max-width: none;
}
```